# Border-right no respecting padding

Tags: css, reactjs

I am currently trying to add a simple `border-right` to my styling. I have padding on the top of the div. The border, however, goes through the padding to the top of the div. Am I missing something when it comes to the styling?

When I replace the `padding` with a `margin` the border responds correctly but I do not want to use a `margin` in this situation.

Here is the styling I am currently using:

```
export const NavigationColumnStyled = styled.div`
  border-right: 1px solid ${({ theme }) => theme.palette.colors.secondary};
  color: ${({ theme }) => theme.typography.onSurface};
  flex: 1;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-top: 25px;
`;
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 3):

That is how it is supposed to work.

The content is a box inside the padding, which is a box inside the border, which is a box inside the margin.

The border extends to the edges of *its* box, not the content box.

See [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#box-model):

[image: Box model]